# Al aplicar pd.cut() me devuelve el error Input array must be 1 dimensional

Tags: python-3.x

Me estoy iniciando en POO. Como ejercicio, me he planteado construir una clase que construya lo que, en estadística, se denomina intervalos de clase.

Esta función, simula un registro de ventas

```
    import numpy as np # importando numpy
    import pandas as pd # importando pandas
    import math
    import os
    
    def datos_ventas():
        np.random.seed(0)  # seed for reproducibility
    
        data = np.random.randint(1, 99, (52, 6))  # 
    
        pd.set_option('precision', 2)
        # array de una lista.
        lista_ventas = data[:,:].flatten()
        # Lista ordenada de datos
        lista_ordenada = np.sort(lista_ventas, axis=None)
        # df de ventas
        df_ventas = pd.DataFrame(data)
        # Crear un df de una única columna, con una lista
        ventas =  pd.DataFrame(lista_ventas)  
        ventas.columns = (["Valores"])
        return df_ventas, lista_ventas, lista_ordenada, ventas
    df_ventas, lista_ventas, lista_ordenada, ventas = datos_ventas()
    ventas[:3]

El siguiente script, me da el error que menciono en el título.

import math

class ConstructoraIntervalos:
    def __init__(self, df, max =0, min=0, M=0, R=0, K=0, C=0):
        self.df = df
        self.max = max
        self.min = min
        self.M = M
        self.R = R
        self.K = K
        self.C = C

        """Número de muestras"""
    def calcula_numero_muestras(self):
        """Número de muestras"""
        self.M = self.df.size
        print ("Numero muestras M:", self.M)

        """Recorrido de la variable""" 
    def calcula_recorrido (self):
        # Variables máxima y mínima
        self.max = self.df.values.max() 
        self.min = self.df.values.min()   
        self.R =  (self.max  - self.min ) 
        print ("Variables máxima y mínima (max, min):",  self.max, self.min)
        print ("Recorrido de la variable :", self.R)

        """Estimación del número de intervalos""" 
    def estima_numero_intervalos(self):
        # Número de muestras M
        #self.M = self.df.size
        self.K = round(1 + 3.322 * math.log10(self.M) )
        print ("Número intervalos K:", self.K)

        """Estimación del Tamaño de los intervalos"""    
    def estima_tamaño_intervalos(self):
        self.lim_inf = self.df.min
        self.lim_sup = self.df.max
        """Tamaño de los intervalos""" 
        self.C = math.ceil( self.R / self.K)
        print ("Tamaño intervalos C:", self.C)

    def crea_intervalos(self):
        intervalos = pd.interval_range( start = self.min, end = self.max, freq = self.C,  name="Intervalo", closed="left")

        df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervalos)
        df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(self.df , bins= df_clases.index).value_counts()
        # Media de cada intervalo del índice
        df_clases["Marca"]  = df_clases.index.mid

        df_clases["LimInf"] = df_clases.index.left

        #Lo instancio como variable de clase al final.
        df_clases["LimSup"] = df_clases.index.right
        print (df_clases)
        return df_clases   
 
    def imprime():
        print ("\nNúmero de muestras M :\n", self.M)
        print ("\nMáximo valor", self.max)
        print ("\nMínimo valor",self.min) 
        print ("\nRecorrido de las variables R :", self.R)
        print ("\nNúmero óptimo de intervalos K:", self.K)
        print ("\nTamaño de los intervalos C:", self.C)
        print (df_clases)
        
        
tabla1 = ConstructoraIntervalos(ventas) 
tabla1.calcula_numero_muestras()
tabla1.calcula_recorrido ()
tabla1.estima_numero_intervalos()
tabla1.estima_tamaño_intervalos()
tabla1.crea_intervalos()


tabla1.imprime()
```

El error que me devuelve es: "ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional" y parece estar relacionado con la sentencia "df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut....." del método "crea_intervalos()"
En esta sentencia, creamos una columna con frecuencias absoluta, en el DataFrame "df_clases.

en el enlace  [https://github.com/akitxu/Consultas-Programacion/blob/master/Crear_Intervalos_Clase.ipynb][1]

mostramos un noetebook con el mismo código, en una secuencia de funciones, sin definición de clases, que opera correctamente.

En el código incluyo sentencias print en los métodos, para facilitar la depuración y ver si las variables tienen o no valores.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este problema?. Agradeceré sus comentarios

El error es:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-b83c5146ed45> in <module>
     69 tabla1.estima_numero_intervalos()
     70 
---> 71 df_clases = tabla1.crea_intervalos()
     72 tabla1.imprime()

<ipython-input-76-b83c5146ed45> in crea_intervalos(self)
     44 
     45         df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervalos)
---> 46         df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(self.df , bins= df_clases.index).value_counts()
     47         # Media de cada intervalo del índice
     48         df_clases["Marca"]  = df_clases.index.mid

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest, duplicates)
    204 
    205     original = x
--> 206     x = _preprocess_for_cut(x)
    207     x, dtype = _coerce_to_type(x)
    208 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in _preprocess_for_cut(x)
    553         x = np.asarray(x)
    554     if x.ndim != 1:
--> 555         raise ValueError("Input array must be 1 dimensional")
    556 
    557     return x

ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional
```

Comment: En qué línea da el error concretamente?

Comment: Incluyo detalles del error en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto poniendo, en la creación del objeto, en lugar del df "ventas", la lista "ventas["Valores"]. En pandas.cut(), el primer parámetro "x" tiene que ser:

Parameters **x** array-like

```
    The input array to be binned. Must be 1-dimensional.
```

Si consideráis que esta pregunta no es útil para otros, la puedo eliminar.

Comment: No hay por qué eliminarla, todo aporte que se base en la normatividad puede resultar útil para distintas personas